# Skip parameter in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a shell-script which handles 3 parameters ($1 $2 and $3). Within the bash I have to skip parameter 2 (I'm actually writing something like ./script.sh para1 para3).

The script is OK. But I can't skip the second parameter. How do I skip this one?

Comment: Why don't you swap the second and third parameters?

Comment: @slybloty That would be easier ;) But we have to skip it. It's a school-project so there's no other way around.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "skipping" refers to? If you don't ever access `$2`, that's perfectly fine. Unless you're using `$@` at some point, I don't see the issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last I've found it:

```
./script.sh "para1" "" "para3"
```

My teacher should be happy with this. He won't get anything else from me.

Comment: To be honest… if I was your teacher, I wouldn't give you (at least not full number of) points for this. ;)

Comment: Did your ask how to run a command with an empty argument, or how to skip an argument within your script.  What you have asked isn't clear.

Comment: even the teacher's solution was the same like this.

Comment: Literal (dutch): 

Oplossing
Dit kan je doen door op de plaats van het 2 argument '' of “” te plaatsen
Voorbeeld: bash <scriptje> eerste '' derde

Answer (score 2):

There's no thing like skipping as you would like.  Arguments are just numbered, if there's no second parameter then… well, there's actually no third parameter.  So either you explicitly give an emptry string as second parameter (if your exercise permits this), or you check how many parameters are given and in case it's two, take the second parameter as third (since it's a school assignment, I won't go into detail here, just have a look at the description of the `$#` special variable in your shell's manual).

Comment: `There's no thing like skipping` - I am not sure I agree with you here.  Between shift, and getopts you can support complex options/arguments.

Comment: To make it clearer:  There's no thing like $3 when $2 isn't there (besides the empty string).  And `getopt` is invalid for the "no-flags" case of `program arg1 [arg2] arg3`.

Answer (score 2):

Using it correctly depends on the context, which isn't clear from your question.  But the command to rename parameters is `shift`

```
$ help shift

shift: shift [n]
    Shift positional parameters.

    Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
    not given, it is assumed to be 1.
```

You would possibly use this in a loop to process a set of arguments.  You could process the first argument as $1, then `shift 2` and third argument would be $1.

For really complex commands you might also use the `getopts` which is what you would use arguments like `./command --foo blah --bar asdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of your 3rd parameter. The `-z` and `-n` operators return successfully if their arguments are empty or nonempty.
Also, throughout your script, use the `para?` variables instead of the numbered arguments.

```
para1=$1
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
    para3=$2
else
    para2=$2
    para3=$3
fi
```